# Morphia gives NoSuchMethodError while saving to DataStore

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, morphia

So I'm trying to use Morphia for MongoDB ORM. Earlier, we were always using the `mongo-java-driver` directly for the CRUD, but ORM makes more sense obviously.

Our `mongo-java-driver` is version 3.1.0, and I am using `morphia` with the current version right now - 1.3.2.

I performed a simple test to get it up and working in a test project with the following code:

```
public class MorphiaTest {

  private Morphia morphia;
  private Datastore datastore;

  public MorphiaTest() {
    this.morphia = new Morphia();

    // should contain all the entity classes that we want to morphia to map
    morphia.mapPackage("com.test.entity");

    MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().build();
    ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(address, options);

    // configure morphia once and use different Datastore instances to connect to multiple databases
    this.datastore = morphia.createDatastore(client, "test");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MorphiaTest morphia = new MorphiaTest();
    GroupProfile profile = new GroupProfile();
    profile.setName("First test group");
    profile.setDescription("Desc for first test group");
    profile.setTs(System.currentTimeMillis());
    profile.setType(0);
    morphia.datastore.save(profile);
  }
```

The `GroupProfile` is an `Entity` that I want to write to a collection in the `test` db in mongo, and is fairly simple.

When I run this I get the following error:

```
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:2}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
Nov 07, 2017 2:48:50 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 15]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, electionId=null, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=554323}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.InsertOptions.getBypassDocumentValidation()Ljava/lang/Boolean;
    at org.mongodb.morphia.InsertOptions.getBypassDocumentValidation(InsertOptions.java:93)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.InsertOptions.copy(InsertOptions.java:36)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.enforceWriteConcern(DatastoreImpl.java:1245)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:775)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:758)
```

Anyone can tell me where I am going wrong?

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bsb.test.morphia</groupId>
  <artifactId>morphiatest</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
      <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.coveo</groupId>
        <artifactId>fmt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I am probably messing up with the dependencies between morphia and the mongo-java-driver, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I think that your morphia module is using your own inclusiong of the mongo-java-driver because you excluded it inside your inclusion of the morphia dependency. The version does not match... Remove the exclusion, I think that might work. You will have 2 different versions of the mongo-java-driver though.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire no, it doesn't work without the exclusion, which was my first attempt.

Comment: But, do you get the same error then? That would be pretty much impossible.

Comment: Yeah, seem to get the same error.

Comment: Then your only option is to remove your own dependency for mongo-java-driver. You should use the one delivered with morphia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Morphia 1.3.2 is compatible with Mongo Java Driver 3.5.0. The Morphia 1.3.2 JAR will deliver that dependency transitively. You are side stepping that transitive dependency with this exclusion:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
  <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Instead, you should remove this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

... and accept the version of the Mongo Java driver which Morphia:1.3.2 is compatible with.

Comment: But is there any way to sidestep the dependency to a lower version of the mongo java driver?

Comment: You could downgrade to a lower version of Morphia i.e. to a version of Morphia which is compatible with v 3.1.0 of the Mongo Java driver. But ... perhaps it's best to think of it like this: you use Morphia to insulate yourself from lower level Mongo Java driver specifics, so it is the responsibility of Morphia to deal with the Mongo Java driver and therefore - as long as you use Morphia - you shouldn't really concern yourself with the version of the Mongo Java driver in use.

Comment: Makes sense. I also verified that mongo driver 3.5.0 is compatible across a wide version range of the db server too. So I don't think there are any issues.